# How to validate the date pattern using HTML5

Tags: regex, html

Hello I am trying to validate date patterns on my checkbox. My patterns are as following : `yyyy` or `m-yyyy` or `d-m-yyyy`

If input is given in the above format then it should be allow otherwise the form shouldn't be submitted. Once the above patterns are inserted I need to compare them with my MYSQL database date field. For example if the year is entered then only match the given year. If the month and year are added then month and year are only compared in database.

I tried the following pattern but it only match full. I need to match all cases

```
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required 
pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))" 
title="Enter a date in this format YYYY-MM-DD"/>
```

How can I achieve the above?

Comment: Any code you've tried you could share with us?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy i posted my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern :

```
((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4})|[0-9]{4}|(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}
```

This is composed of 3 parts :

- (0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}

Which checks for the format `DD.MM.YYYY`

- [0-9]{4}

Which checks for the format `YYYY`

- (0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}

Which checks for the format `MM-YYY`

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="YYYY or MM-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY" required pattern="((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4})|[0-9]{4}|(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}" />
  <button type="submit">test</button>
</form>
```

Comment: yes thats great for front side validation. working good. is there any way that i can directly compare the input in the mysql date field. for example if added year only then it gets the record of that whole year. if MM-YYYY added then it gets records only for that month and year only

Comment: @CodeEmbassy there's no easy and quick way of doing that, you'd need to use ajax to get the result of your form then send it to a PHP page that checks the information in the datatabase and give you back a result you could use to show the user. In terms of the current question I think I've already answered it. Feel free to try what you just described and if you get stuck post another question! :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the regular expression already discussed to split the incoming data into 1, 2, or 3 fields, say $d, $m, $y, some of which are NULL.
2. Build a query with the suitable WHERE clause based on the data:

Something like this in PHP, assuming `dt` is the column being tested against:

```
$wheres = array();
$wheres[] = "'$y' = LEFT(dt, 4)";             -- test the Year
if (isset($m))
    $wheres[] = "0+'$m' = 0+MID(dt, 6, 2)";   -- and month (if given)
if (isset($d))
    $wheres[] = "0+'$d' = 0+MID(dt, 9, 2)";

$where_clause = implode(" AND ", $wheres);    -- put the tests together
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE ( $where_clause ) ...";
```

Notes:  `0+` is for avoiding string compares for, say, month='3' versus '03'.